# Nvidia Graphic installed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee

I have an Optimus graphic card and had the blank screen issue after installing Nvidia drivers.

I think I installed Bumblebee drivers correctly and everything is running correctly. But, in the Graphics category of System Details, it says graphic driver **Unknown**.

**Questions:**

1. Was bumblebee installed correctly and do I now have power management working in my laptop?
2. Is Nvidia now the primary graphic card (the laptop also has Intel mobility)?
3. And if not, if I want to run apps with it, I just have to write optirun in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

1. To see the correct driver in System Details you have to install mesa-utils
   just run this command in terminal:

   `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`
2. To verify if Bumblebee is correctly installed you have to type this command:

   `optirun --status`

You should see sth like that:

```
`Bumblebee status:  Ready (3.0.1). X inactive. Discrete video card is off.`
```

1. No, Intel is primary card. To run something with NVIDIA you have to type the following command

   `optirun [application]`